# Avoiding String.ValueOf on Map<String, Object> from JSON

Tags: rest-api, json, data-types, casting

I'm working on a JSON response that is a REST api call making a Query to another Salesforce Org.

### Important points:

1. I'm trying to avoid using JSON2APEX if I can. So far I have had good success, and if possible would like to continue this strategy.
2. I'm trying insert the new campaigns without having to do a lot of String.ValueOf(m.get(value)); syntax. Its not a huge deal to do String.valueOf in this instance, but I can imagine a scenario where it would not be sufficient.

### Questions

- Do I need to change the way I'm casting the individual records to a map?
- Is my only alternative to use JSON2Apex Class?

### Code Sample:

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());
        List<Map<String, Object>> myMaps = new List<Map<String, Object>>(); 
        List<Object> myList = (List<Object>)results.get('records'); 
        for(Object obj : myList){
            myMaps.add((Map<String, Object>)obj);
        }
        //Start the process to create Parent Records 
        for(Map<String, Object> m : myMaps ){
            System.debug(m.keySet());
            System.debug(m.get('Name'));
            System.debug(m.get('Id'));
            Campaign cam = new Campaign(
                Name = String.valueOf(m.get('Name')) + ' test', 
                Status = String.valueOf(m.get('Status')), 
                Description = m.get('Description'), 
                Category__c = m.get('Category'), 
                Type = m.get('General'), 
                RecordTypeId = recId

            ); 
            newCampaigns.add(cam);
```

### JSON Example

```
{
    "totalSize": 3,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Campaign",
                "url": ""
            },
            "Id": "aklsjfd;alskj",
            "Name": "Membership - Digital Test",
            "Default_Designation__r": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Designation__c",
                    "url": ""
                },
                "Name": "test designation"
            },
            "Parent": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Campaign",
                    "url": ""
                },
                "Name": "My Memberships"
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Campaign",
                "url": ""
            },
            "Id": "oiqupeoiua;kgdh",
            "Name": "CA Memberships",
            "Default_Designation__r": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Designation__c",
                    "url": ""
                },
                "Name": "test designation"
            },
            "Parent": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Campaign",
                    "url": ""
                },
                "Name": "My Memberships"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specifically use a JSON2Apex Class, but using an inner class to deserialize the string is VERY useful.

If you define an inner class like this:

```
public class RestResponse {
  public Integer totalSize;
  public Boolean done;
  public List<Record> records;
}

public class Default_Designation__r {
  public Attributes attributes;
  public String Name;
}

public class Record {
  public String Id;
  public String Name;
  public Default_Designation__r Default_Designation__r;
  public Default_Designation__r Parent;
}
```

In your main class, you can deserialize the response into this and get all the attributes much more easily.

```
String httpResponse = resp.getBody();
RestResponse resp = (RestResponse)JSON.deserialize(httpResponse,RestResponse.class);
```

Note the these are all inner classes of your main class, and that they are all at the same level - There is no parsing code, no attributes (I assumed you wouldn't want those)

If you don't want things like Default_Designation__r, you can define your class like this:

```
public class DefaultDesignation {
  public Attributes attributes;
  public String Name;
}
```

And do a string replace before deserializing:

```
while (httpResponse.contains('Default_Designation__r')){
  httpResponse.replace('Default_Designation__r','DefaultDesignation');
}
```

To create campaigns, you loop on the records:

```
for (Record record : resp.records){
  Campaign cam = new Campaign(
      Name = record.Name + 'test',
      Status = record.Status,
      Description = record.Description,
      Category__c = record.Category
      Type = record.General, /* do you mean 'General'*/
      RecordTypeId = recId
  ); 
  newCampaigns.add(cam); 
}
```

Note... your JSON does not contain `Description` or `Category` or `General`. Also if you don't want `Designation` - you can just remove it from the inner class and it will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks trying this out now. I slimmed the JSON down so it was more readable. In the source code those additional values are there.

Comment: Working through a bug. I'm getting --> Invalid type: RestResponse.Records My code will keep you posted on if it works.

Comment: Actually, rename the `Records` class to `Record` - I have a couple of things to fix

Comment: No worries. I'm trying a couple things as well. Still getting invalid type on that one.

Comment: Ok take a look. essentially there is no `Response.Records` type = it's just `Record`

Comment: Yup! Just got it at the same time! Thank you sir